# Delete text between two tags with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello there fellow developers, I am trying to delete a certain character between two tags using jQuery:

```html
<div class="product-details">
  <p class="product-name">Gastronormbehälter PROFI GN 1/6 - 150</p>
  <strong>1</strong> x
  <span class="price">9,14&nbsp;€</span>
</div>
```

In this case the "x" between the strong and the span tag. I can't search for "x" in the product-details class because there could be an "x" in the name of the product. Thats why I thought it would be the best thing to say that everything between the `<strong>` and `<span>` should be deleted.

Also this must be done using jQuery, I have no access to this code to delete it myself. Hope anybody has a solution for me since nothing worked for me so far.

Comment: Why do you need jQuery? Why not just standard no-library Javascript? Also, your HTML there is invalid - you should consider fixing that first.

Comment: why is it invalid?

Comment: Well, it *was* invalid. `<p class="product-name">Gastronormbehälter PROFI GN 1/6 - 150</a></p>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the example you can simply remove all child textNodes from the `.product-details` div. You can do that in jQuery by using `contents()`, `filter()` then `remove()`:

```js
$('.product-details').contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType == 3 && this.nodeValue.trim();
}).remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product-details">
  <p class="product-name">Gastronormbehälter PROFI GN 1/6 - 150</p>
  <strong>1</strong> 
  x
  <span class="price">9,14&nbsp;€</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, You can get target the node element using DOM relationship. Here in example, You can get a reference to `<strong>` node then get desired element using [`nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling)

```js
var element = document.querySelector('.product-details > strong');
//element.nextSibling.nodeValue = "Modified Value";

element.nextSibling.parentNode.removeChild(element.nextSibling)
```

```html
<div class="product-details">
  <p class="product-name">Gastronormbehälter PROFI GN 1/6 - 150</p>
  <strong>1</strong> x
  <span class="price">9,14&nbsp;€</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$('.product-details').children()` to get the elements with the tag. Since, `x` do not have any tag this will be removed. Then, set this result as the new html content of `.product-details`.

```js
$('.product-details').html($('.product-details').children());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product-details">
<p class="product-name">Gastronormbehälter PROFI GN 1/6 - 150</p>
<strong>1</strong>
 x
<span class="price">9,14&nbsp;€</span>
</div>
```

Comment: @Kesaja you can tick mark the answer if it was helpful to you